# Why is the data not being saved?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am getting a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when I am trying to open a notification onto a certain view controller. I think I know why, there are some variables which are nil, causing the app to crash, but I am trying to give those variables data, but they are not saving.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
     PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
  let text = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]
    let title = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]!!["title"]
    let artist = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]!!["artist"]
    print(text)
    print(title)
    print(artist)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerController") as! PlayerViewController
    vc.dataModel.artistplay = artist as? String
    vc.dataModel.titleplay = title as? String
    window?.rootViewController = vc

    }
```

This is the code for the PlayerViewController (The view controller I am trying to open when the push notification is opened)

```
 @IBOutlet weak var playertitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playerartist: UILabel!
var dicData : NSDictionary?
var dataModel : DataModelTwo?
var data: NSDictionary?
var shareDataModel: Share?
var buttonState: Int = 0;

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    playertitle.text = dataModel!.titleplay
    playerartist.text = dataModel!.artistplay

}
```

Answer (score 1):

do NOT set UILable text from AppDelegate.
set a variable in your ViewController then use it in `viewDidLoad`.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
  PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
  let text = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]
  print(text)
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerController") as! PlayerViewController
  vc.foo = "bar"
  window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

use variables and update UI :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     print(self.foo) // output is "bar"
}
```

Comment: I am passing info from one view controller from another, it is based on what the user chooses then that is what the playertitle is, should I still use viewDidLoad?\

Comment: Simple , UILabel is not initialized yet ! ,

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that in the beginning, they are initialized

Comment: @stackerleet did you find the answer ?!

Comment: Yes I did, I updated my code with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you show, the `dataModel` in PlayerViewController is not initialized and, as it is an optional, its value is `nil`. Since you're implicitly unwrapping - `dataModel!` it causes the crash.
Initialize first the `dataModel`and then use it to get the values you want.

Comment: Where should I initialize datamodel? In the App delegate or the PlayerViewController?

Comment: It's up to you to decide where is the best place. Without more information I would do it in the PlayerViewController.

Comment: This is what dataModel looks like, http://puu.sh/m8AoJ/c95c0b807c.png. And the strings are based on what is contained in the notification.

Comment: `class DataModelTwo : NSObject{
    var titleplay: String?
    var artistplay: String?
}
`

Comment: Does this class have an initializer?

Comment: What I put in the previous comment is all there is to the class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98991/discussion-between-rui-barbosa-and-stackerleet).